# Leadtools.kernel.annotations.dll specified module could not be found

Tags: .net, dll-injection

I have a simple app that makes a call to Leadtools.Annotations.AnnCodecs.SaveToTag(AnnContainer container, AnnCodecsTagFormat format).  That method attempts to use System.Reflection.Assembly to load Leadtools.Kernel.Annotations.dll, but the operation fails on a specific machine with the following error

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E

I have used ProcMon and verified that QueryOpen and CreateFile result in success against the dll.  I have also used DependencyWalker in profiling mode with no luck.  The only dll it can't find is IESHIMS which is also missing from the machines that can run the application.

The application runs without error on other machines.

### Update

Using ILSpy I was able to see the offending line is

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("Leadtools.Kernel.Annotations");
```

That call simply does not work on the specified machine but does work on all other machines I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved after writing the same test file using C++.  With the C++ version the test app threw an exception specifying MSVCP71.dll was not found.

```
This application has failed to start because MSVCP71.dll was not found.  
Re-installing the application may fix this problem.
```

The specific dll really isn't the point though.  The point is that this type of issue could probably be resolved easily by following this approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is Daoud from LEADTOOLS support.
I'm posting more details about this issue since Reid contacted us and one of my colleagues we worked with him.

The version used is v14.5, which is old and out of production. The Windows version used is Windows Server 2008 standard. Windows 2008 was never officially supported with v14.5. Server 2008 came out after Windows Vista, which also wasn’t officially supported with v14.5. However, we did patch it to make it compatible.

As for your issue, I can see from the ticket that after using the latest setup, the issue was fixed and everything works well again.

Please do not hesitate to contact us if you face any problem with LEADTOOLS.

LEADTOOLS support

Comment: It should be noted that the dll is working in all other server instances (same os) where it is installed.  I still have no resolution on why it works for all of those other servers and not this specific one.